# Laws and Intuition for physical problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

So I've been reading the book 'Feynman: Tips on Physics' recently and in chapter 2 (the book is available for free online) he works out the answer for this problem using his intuition rather than bashing using mathematics.

[image: Problem:]

He then goes on to explain his thought process:

[image]

However I don't understand how he determines the **horizontal force** i.e. I don't understand his reasoning here:

'The corresponding horizontal force on each leg must be the fraction of the vertical force, that is merely the horizontal to vertical ratio in the right triangle, which is 3 to 4.'

*So here are my questions:*

- Why must the 'corresponding' force on each leg be the 'fraction of 
  the vertical force?' How does one come to this conclusion?
- Why is this merely the 'horizontal to vertical ratio in the right
  triangle? (Aren't angles involved in components of forces) How does
  one understand this intuitively and how can apply this to other
  problems in the future?

Again I am looking to intuitive explanation on how to approach these problems in this sort of way and an explanation behind Mr. Feynman's reasoning.

Comment: Feynman recognized many simple geometric relationships, so he didn't nee to work out the Pythagorean theorem. This saves steps for problems that are stated using these simple figures.

Comment: It would be interesting to see, how many different solutions PSE can find to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to think about it. If you apply force $P$ at the roller, and push the roller forward, say a small horizontal distance $\delta d$, then you've done work $P\times\delta d$. At the same time, the mass $m=2\mbox{kg}$ has risen some small corresponding height $\delta h$, thereby gaining potential energy $mg\times\delta h$. So either $P\times \delta d=mg\times\delta h$, or else you've solved the world's energy problems. Thus, $P/mg=\delta h/\delta d$, and all you need is that $\delta h/\delta d$ ratio, which you get from the triangle. (P.S. Energy arguments are often the easiest=most_intuitive way to think about these kinds of problems, and to solve them with minimal math. So spend a few seconds to see if maybe they're applicable, before thinking about kinematic free-body diagrams, or about F=ma, etc.)

Comment: This is a very good alternative solution to the problem, but it doesn't really answer my questions.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an answer, per se. Intuition, I think, is something you just "get". To put it another way, nobody can teach you(anybody) anything that requires "understanding" (anything other than rote memorization). All they can do is tell you about it, describing their own understanding. Eventually you'll hopefully have an "aha moment", and say "now I get it". But that happens entirely in your own head (presumably with some help from what you've been told). Exactly likewise for intuition -- nobody can just tell you. Just give you some examples, and then you'll hopefully see it yourself.